# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed! on Nutch 1.7

Tags: apache, search, solr, nutch

Solr and Nutch are already setup locally (on separate directories) and I wish to crawl a URL, index it, then integrate that index into Solr.

Running this crawl on terminal:

```
                $ bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5
```

Reports this error on the command line:

```
                Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
                        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
                        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:123)
                        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:81)
                        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:65)
                        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:155)
                        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
                        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

That said, in my attempt to then integrate I run this command:

```
                $ bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

Which reports this error on the command line:

```
                2013-10-23 13:23:38.347 java[15444:1203] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
                Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
                        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
                        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:123)
                        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:185)
                        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
                        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:195)
```

My environment and app versions are as follows:

- Nutch 1.7
- Solr 4.5
- MAC OSX (10.8.5)
- java version "1.6.0_51"

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you put your logs/hadoop.log file in pastebin?

Comment: 1. For the crawl with Nutch  
    - http://pastebin.com/zDhips3x  
2. For the index to Solr  
    - http://pastebin.com/mMNSWuwg

Comment: Just noticed you are using "http://localhost:8983/solr/" as the solr index url.   Can you try again but using the url to your solr index name? e.g. "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1"

Comment: Crawl and index was successful. I can't express enough thank u's @nimeshjm

Comment: On a side-note, I plan on using the ajax-solr JavaScript framework to integrate the JSON to the front-end. Any opinions, reservation or advice as I approach this portion of Solr integration?

Comment: I have never used ajax-solr so I can't comment on it. I have used SOLR.NET ( https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet ) in my applications and I can vouch for it.  It will all depend on your front-end application and your use cases...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I resolved the problem by including the core in the command

1. Find your core name

   1a. go to http://localhost:8983/solr

   1b. on the left-hand navigation, there is a pull down menu titled "Core Selector", click on the menu and see a list of Solr core.

   1c. write down the core name. (ex: collection1)
2. Put the core name in the command

   2a. $ bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/**collection1** crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*

Answer (score 0):

Mr Mrkreyes do you got an answer for your problem's nutch